# Does delete[] deallocate the entire block of memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, delete-operator

Consider the following:

```
char* msg = new char[20]; 
msg[4] = '\0'; 
delete[] msg;
```

1. Did the `delete[] msg` deallocate all the 20 chars allocated for `msg` or just those up to the `\0`?
2. If it deallocated only up to the `\0`, how can I force it to delete the entire block of memory?

Comment: Of course not. If so, you couldn't alloc anything else than a string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original code in your question had undefined behaviour, since you were using `delete` with `new[]`.

I notice that you have fixed it by replacing the `delete` with `delete[]`:

```
delete[] msg;
```

This is correct, and will deallocate all memory that's been allocated by `new[]`.

There is no concept of "deleting till `\0`", or any other such "partial" deletion. Only *complete* blocks allocated with `new`/`new[]` can be deleted, so your code is fine.

Comment: In many implementations (e.g. clang's `libstdc++`), `new` & `new[]` are synonymous with `malloc`, and `delete` and `delete[]` for `free`. That means that it won't make a difference in those scenarios.

Comment: OK  , I changed  , and now ?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Firstly, `new` can't be synonymous with `malloc` since it has different semantics (calls the constructor). Even if the three are based on the same allocator, this doesn't change the fact that technically the behaviour is undefined. I can show you lots of other examples which happen to work on some platforms using some compilers, but that rely on undefined behaviour and are therefore not portable.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: Even if `new`/`delete` uses `malloc`/`free` underneath, the former calls constructors/destructors for you, while the latter does not. That is a significant difference in semantics.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's like saying *there's `xyz` implementation that does garbage collection, so you never need to use `delete`*. How is it relevant at all?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Even if the particular *internal* details of how those operations allocate memory match that is still **irrelevant**:  There are *huge* differences between new and new[] (and delete/delete[]) and they got nothing to do with memory allocation per se. Please don't provide incomplete, inaccurate or blatantly wrong answers or comments. It does a disservice to everyone - yourself included.

Answer (score 5):

The `delete[]` operator deletes the entire block of memory. You cannot deallocate part of block of memory – you can only deallocate the entire block.

This is also the case for `new/delete`, and `malloc/free`. The deallocating function can only deallocate the entire block of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `delete[]` to free an array. That's the only way you can tell the program to look for array information and be able to free the whole array.

With a normal `delete` the compiler may think that you want to deallocate just a single pointer and this is not the case. The extra information about the size of the array and whatever won't be looked for and extra memory won't be freed.

The fact that you set a char inside the array to `\0`  doesn't make any difference, when releasing the array only the known size of the array is considered. Otherwise anything similar to

```
Class *array = new Class[50];
array[0] = NULL;
delete[] array;
```

would just leak memory.